# Java 7: Actual Date format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: java, date

On my DB i have a date column with this format: '2016-10-05'

How can i obtain the actual date on this format?

I tried with

```
Date date = new Date();
```

But the format is not compatible and it doesen't works.

Comment: Did you try to search on Google ? Java date formatter ?

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat to get desired date format..

Comment: @Removed Actually, yes. You would have found official doc from Java, same questionS from SO with answerS.

Comment: @Removed yes we are polite as you can see downvotes. More the downvotes means more polite

Comment: @Removed you're not gonna get far on this website with that attitude. And he's correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(stringWithDate);
```

You have to use `SimpleDataFormat` which allows you to parse `String`s with different formats to `Date`

Comment: why you are answering duplicate questions?

Comment: To help new user who might help the others in a very future.

Comment: But there are many questions similar to this and it has been answered. It is against the stackoverflow to have duplicate questions. If you want to help new user then please answer new questions. If you know have a different answer for a duplicate question then please answer in the old question and do not answer in the duplicated question